# How much gas fees does to take if we code dao from scratch and if we use existing tools?

Tags: dapps, the-dao, dao

1. How much gas fees does it take, if we deploy a DAO which was built from scratch on Ethereum
2. How much gas fees does it take, if we use existing DAO deploying tools like Aragon, Syndicate, etc
3. Which way is better to deploy DAO from the above 2 methods or Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on your implementation.
2. Aragon takes a whopping 0.2 ETH to create a DAO. DAOHaus takes a more moderate 0.02 ETH. Finally, Syndicate currently takes about 0.01 ETH. Snapshot.org is special in that it requires an ENS address. Beyond that, I believe it to be pretty cheap to use. Finally, tally.xyz is a weird middle ground between 1 and 2. Personally, I'd only use it if I felt very comfortable with this kind of thing.
3. Definitely use a pre-existing solution. The risk that you might introduce a major bug means that you should always endeavor to use someone else's tried and tested code as opposed to your own brand new code.